# Rest assured - How to validate JSON response field with the same name

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the sample JSON response

```
     "userinfo": [
            {
                "userName": "name1",
                "registered": false
            },
            {
                "userName": "name2",
                "registered": true
            }
          ]
```

How can I verify when `userName = name1` then `registered = false`
When `userName = name2` then `registered = true`

Tried something like this but it does not work.

```
.body("$.findAll{it.userinfo.userName = name1"}.registered", equalTo(false));
```

Did I miss something or do something wrong?

Comment: Try to look into this.https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that can help you out,

```
    String json = "{\r\n" + "   \"userinfo\": [{\r\n" + "           \"userName\": \"name1\",\r\n"
            + "         \"registered\": false\r\n" + "      },\r\n" + "     {\r\n"
            + "         \"userName\": \"name2\",\r\n" + "           \"registered\": true\r\n" + "       }\r\n"
            + " ]\r\n" + "}";

    JsonPath js = new JsonPath(json);
    String emp1Name = js.get("userinfo.find {it.userName == 'name2'}.registered").toString();
    System.out.println(emp1Name);
```